# Docker compose for Kafka with SASL SCRAM authentication fails

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I am attempting to create a Docker Compose setup with:

- 1 Zookeeper
- 2 Kafka Brokers
- 1 Kafka UI

Kafka clients should use `SCRAM-SHA-512` authentication - I do not care how the brokers and Zookeeper authenticate with each other. I also do not want SSL.

To simplify, I am trying to get this working:

- 1 Zookeeper
- 1 Kafka Broker

Here is what I have so far:

`zookeeper_jaas.conf`

```
Server {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="password123"
  user_admin="password123";
};

Client {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="password123";
};
```

`kafka_jaas.conf`

```
KafkaServer {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="password123"
  user_admin="password123";
};

KafkaClient {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="password123";
};

Client {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="password123";
};
```

`docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3.5'
services:

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.2
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_DATA_DIR: /tmp/zookeeper
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181
      ZOOKEEPER_MAX_CLIENT_CNXNS: 0
      ZOOKEEPER_AUTH_PROVIDER_1: org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
      ZOOKEEPER_REQUIRE_CLIENT_AUTH_SCHEME: sasl
      ZOOKEEPER_JAAS_LOGIN_RENEW: 3600000
      KAFKA_OPTS: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/secrets/zookeeper_server_jaas.conf
    networks:
      - kafka-cluster-network
    volumes:
      - ./zookeeper_jaas.conf:/etc/kafka/secrets/zookeeper_server_jaas.conf

  kafka_broker_a:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.2
    hostname: kafka_broker_a
    container_name: kafka_broker_a
    depends_on:
      zookeeper:
        condition: service_started
    healthcheck:
      test: nc -vz kafka_broker_a 19093 || exit -1
      start_period: 10s
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 15s
      retries: 10
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:22181
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_SASL_ENABLED: "true"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_SASL_CLIENT: "true"
      KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka_broker_a
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SASL_PLAINTEXT://kafka_broker_a:19094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: SASL_PLAINTEXT://kafka_broker_a:19094
      KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM: SCRAM-SHA-512
      KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: SCRAM-SHA-512
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: SCRAM-SHA-512
      KAFKA_SUPER_USERS: User:admin
      KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: "false"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLED: "false"
      KAFKA_OPTS: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/secrets/conf/kafka_jaas.conf
    volumes:
      - ./kafka_jaas.conf:/etc/kafka/secrets/conf/kafka_jaas.conf
    networks:
      - kafka-cluster-network

networks:
  kafka-cluster-network:
    driver: bridge
    name: kafka-cluster-network
```

However, this leads to errors like so:

```
kafka_broker_a    | [2023-05-10 14:27:44,071] INFO [Controller id=1, targetBrokerId=1] Node 1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka_broker_a    | [2023-05-10 14:27:44,071] ERROR [Controller id=1, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 (kafka_broker_a/172.23.0.3:19094) failed authentication due to: Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-512 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

I do not understand why the credentials are invalid since they are in the JAAS configs.